# Energy Oscillations in a One Dimensional Crystal

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions, functional-equations, bessel-functions

Good day!

Can anyone help me find articles on similar topics "Energy Oscillations in a One Dimensional Crystal" (I have links to one article on this subject)?

[article, that I have](http://mech.spbstu.ru/images/1/1e/Energy_Oscillations.pdf)

Especially interested in issues:

1. "One of the theoretical questions in the mechanics of discrete media is associated with high frequency oscillations of the kinetic and potential energies, which are known well by the results of numerical modeling. In particular, if at the initial instant the particles are ordered into the ideal crystal lattice and their velocities are specified randomly, then the dynamic transition of the kinetic energy into the potential energy of the bonds deformation is initiated in the crystal. This transition leads to the distribution of the internal energy between the kinetic and deformation degrees of freedom, which are determined by the virial theorem [10]. **However, the transition is accompanied by high frequency oscillatory process with decreasing amplitude, which still has no theoretical interpretation."

**Is last sentence true?**

2. "Thus, we derived an exact analytical solution, according to which the Lagrangian function for the chain with the stochastic initial conditions varies following the same law, according to which the central particle for the chain with the deterministic initial conditions moves."
3. "The variation in the kinetic and potential energies of the system under consideration is described by the Bessel function, the oscillation period of which is T0/4, while the amplitude of oscillations is inversely proportional to the root of time."
4. "It follows from the found solution that the damping of oscillations of energies is determined by excitation of correlations, which associates the motion of the particles remote from each other."
   **Points 2-4 are the original or they have already been described in scientific articles?**

Comment: Points 1-4 seems to be direct quotes from the article. Maybe you should make that clear by (at the very least) putting quotation marks around them.

Comment: Given your specific questions it seems that you are asking for an evaluation of the paper that you attached. Your general question seems to be asking about a literature search. Please see our previous Meta discussions on whether such questions are on-topic at MathOverflow: [literature search](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1516/3948), [correctness of papers](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/927/3948) (though this last discussion focuses more on preprints).

Comment: Other publications of the same author can be found here http://tm.spbstu.ru/%D0%90.%D0%9C._%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2:_%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 and here http://www.ipme.ru/ipme/labs/msm/Pub/index.html

Comment: I know that Other publications of the same author can be found here tm.spbstu.ru/… and here  ipme.ru/ipme/labs/msm/Pub/index.html, but I need similar articles from other author. I want to check out this article on the original material. I help this author.